# Httpunit test - how to retrieve cookie value

Tags: java, webclient, http-unit

I have written 'Httpunit' test for my web application and I want to retrieve cookies ,but when I am using "web.getCookieValue(String value);" it's returning null .

This is my code:

```
 public class Test_9 extends TestCase  {

   public void test_9() throws Exception {
     WebConversation web = new WebConversation();
     WebRequest  request = new PostMethodWebRequest("http://localhost:8090/get"  );
     web.getCookieValue("auth");
     request.setParameter("table", "activity");
     request.setParameter("id", "0");
     request.setParameter("subset", "null");
     WebResponse response = web.getResource(request);
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.getText());
     boolean success = json.getBoolean("success");

     if(success){
        System.err.println("/getActivities :"+json.toString());
     }
     else{
        assertEquals(false, success);
        String message = json.getString("msg");
        System.err.println("/getActivities :"+message);
     }
 }
}
```

Please help me 
thanks in advance :).

Comment: I guess, You are placing the "web.getCookieValue(String value);" at a wrong place. Try to put this line after sending the request to server. You can try this line after this line "WebResponse response = web.getResource(request);"

Comment: I tried whatever said ,but its not working.

Comment: Why do you use `getResource`? Try `getResponse` instead. It says that `getResource` does not update client and cookies is client update: http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/WebClient.html#getResource%28com.meterware.httpunit.WebRequest%29

Comment: Even after using getResponse,still web.getCookieValue(String value) is returning null.:(